# Check if device is rooted using /system

Tags: android, security

Is there any way to get these filesystems mounted with the "rw" flag.

I am trying to detect if the device is rooted or not by Checking for writable partitions and system directories in files of android devices.

Thanks in advance for your helping :).

Comment: if ( new File ("/data").list() == null || new File("/data").list().isEmpty() ) ......

Answer (score 0):

Well, what else can I say.

## Test 1

```
File dir = new File("/system");
if(dir.canRead() && dir.canWrite()) {
   System.out.println("Can read and write in this directory. (rw)");
} else if(dir.canRead()) {
    System.out.println("Can read in this directory (r)");
} else if(dir.canWrite()) {
    System.out.println("Can write in this directory (w).");
}
```

Output

```
Can read in this directory (r)
```

```
$ mount | grep '/system'
/dev/block/platform/13540000.dwmmc0/by-name/SYSTEM /system ext4 ro,seclabel,relatime,norecovery 0 0
```

## Test 2

```
dir = new File("/storage/emulated/0");
if(dir.canRead() && dir.canWrite()) {
   System.out.println("Can read and write in this directory. (rw)");
} else if(dir.canRead()) {
   System.out.println("Can read in this directory (r)");
} else if(dir.canWrite()) {
   System.out.println("Can write in this directory (w).");
}
```

Output

```
Can read and write in this directory. (rw)
```

```
$ mount | grep '/storage/emulated'
/data/media /storage/emulated sdcardfs rw,seclabel,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,low_uid=1023,low_gid=1023,gid=9997,multi_user,mask=0007,reserved=20MB 0 0
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I have a question: Are there differences in policy between companies related to these system files?
Like in Samsung they are RW and in Huawei they are not?

Comment: @AshrafEzouli Not sure about that, but the best way it's to do some checking mechanisms so it doesn't matter what devices your app is running on, you'll always get the same consistency.

Comment: I hope that.
Thanks a lot, you helped me well :)